# Flip vertically a bitmap image (unidimensional array)

Tags: c, algorithm

I have an unidimensional array (BitMap[i]) that is upside down. How to flip it vertically in C?

This code flips it horizontally, but I need to flip it vertically (x-axis):

```
  for(int row = 0; row < image_height; ++row) {
      for(int column = 0; column < image_width; ++column) {
          flipped_BitMap[row*image_width + column] = BitMap[row*image_width + (image_width-1 - column)];
      }
  }
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: This not a C problem. Stop and think about it.

Comment: Can you explain in prose how you did the horizontal flipping?

Comment: @Yunnosch I found the algorithm on the internet and I changed it to work on my code. Btw, the flipped bitmap takes value of the old bitmap and the column values are decreased by a value

Comment: Don't you need to swap the elements in the top row with the elements in the bottom row, and the second top row with the second bottom row, etc?  Your code is swapping elements on row; you need to swap elements in a column.  Or, since you aren't doing the flipping in situ, don't you need to copy the top row of the original image to the bottom row of the flipped image, and the second row of the original to the second from bottom row of the flipped image.

Comment: Try a search and replace on your code: swap "row" for "column" and "width" for "height" (within identifiers, too). Then use a debugger to watch what happens, or how it goes wrong. You probably need to multiply by line-width somewhere.

Comment: @Yunnosch it doesn't change anything

Comment: @JonathanLeffler how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you were changing the image in situ, you would need to swap the elements in the top row with the elements in the bottom row, and the second top row with the second bottom row, etc.

Since you aren't doing the flipping in situ but are making a copy, you need to copy the top row of the original image to the bottom row of the flipped image, and the second row of the original to the second from bottom row of the flipped image.  Reducing the identifiers to manageable lengths so that single lines of code can be read without scrolling off the RHS of the page:

```
int ht = image_height;
int wd = image_width;
for (int row = 0; row < ht; ++row)
{
     for (int col = 0; col < wd; ++col)
     {
          flipped_BitMap[(ht - row - 1) * wd + col] = BitMap[row * wd + col];
     }
}
```

You could forcibly use variables for the `(ht - row - 1) * wd` and `row * wd` terms in the array indexes.  However, moving such loop-invariant expressions out of the loop is a basic step for any optimizer, so it is unlikely to be critical that you do it explicitly.  In some circumstances, similar 'optimizations' might even be counter-productive.

```
int ht = image_height;
int wd = image_width;
for (int row = 0; row < ht; ++row)
{
     int tgt_off = (ht - row - 1) * wd;   // Start of target row
     int src_off = row * wd;              // Start of source row
     for (int col = 0; col < wd; ++col)
     {
          flipped_BitMap[tgt_off + col] = BitMap[src_off + col];
     }
}
```

You could reverse the expressions for source and target row and, although you'd process the data slightly differently, the net result would be the same.

#### Proof of concept

Here's a test program used to satisfy me that the code should do as intended.  Note that variables have been renamed ruthlessly, but the horizontal flip code is cribbed from the question, and the vertical flip code is cribbed from the previous part of the answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void dump_bitmap(const char *tag, int rows, int cols, int bitmap[])
{
    printf("%s (%dx%d):\n", tag, rows, cols);
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            printf(" %.2X", bitmap[r * cols + c]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    enum { ROWS = 8, COLS = 6 };
    // random -n 48 0 255 | commalist -b '        ' -n 6 -W 4
    int source[ROWS * COLS] =
    {
        134,  185,  171,  136,  117,  219,
        115,  133,  102,   51,  146,   86,
        210,  138,  195,   30,  202,  106,
        161,  157,  199,  152,  179,  120,
        113,   76,   73,  119,   40,  248,
        243,  177,   72,   45,  226,  220,
        101,  121,  206,  168,  156,  148,
        106,    1,  248,   61,   60,  211,
    };
    int h_flip[ROWS * COLS];
    int v_flip[ROWS * COLS];

    dump_bitmap("Original", ROWS, COLS, source);
    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < COLS; ++col)
        {
            h_flip[row * COLS + col] = source[row * COLS + (COLS - 1 - col)];
        }
    }
    dump_bitmap("H-Flip", ROWS, COLS, h_flip);

    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < COLS; ++col)
        {
            v_flip[(ROWS - row - 1) * COLS + col] = source[row * COLS + col];
        }
    }
    dump_bitmap("V-Flip", ROWS, COLS, v_flip);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample output

```
Original (8x6):
 86 B9 AB 88 75 DB
 73 85 66 33 92 56
 D2 8A C3 1E CA 6A
 A1 9D C7 98 B3 78
 71 4C 49 77 28 F8
 F3 B1 48 2D E2 DC
 65 79 CE A8 9C 94
 6A 01 F8 3D 3C D3
H-Flip (8x6):
 DB 75 88 AB B9 86
 56 92 33 66 85 73
 6A CA 1E C3 8A D2
 78 B3 98 C7 9D A1
 F8 28 77 49 4C 71
 DC E2 2D 48 B1 F3
 94 9C A8 CE 79 65
 D3 3C 3D F8 01 6A
V-Flip (8x6):
 6A 01 F8 3D 3C D3
 65 79 CE A8 9C 94
 F3 B1 48 2D E2 DC
 71 4C 49 77 28 F8
 A1 9D C7 98 B3 78
 D2 8A C3 1E CA 6A
 73 85 66 33 92 56
 86 B9 AB 88 75 DB
```

If there is a problem seeing the vertically flipped image, then I suggest that the problem is either in the transcription of the code or somewhere else outside the scope of the vertical flipping code, at least until there's further information available to diagnose what is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your code seems to be ok, but now I can't see my picture on my debugger at all.

Comment: Funny, I can't see the image on your debugger either.  I'm working off your code that reversed the rows of the image.  That looked OK.  Were you able to get your horizontally flipped image to display in the debugger?  If so, the vertically flipped image should also be displayable.  If that's not part of the solution, write a function to display an image as bytes.  Keep your image size down to 16x16 or smaller, and dump it in hex.  Then compare the original with the flipped data — for both the horizontally flipped and vertically flipped images.

Comment: There are endless things that could be wrong — and many if not most would be in code other than this fragment.  If you still need help, you'll have to consider adding a bit more code to your question.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  _Warning:_ I have not tested the code I showed; I don't have the data on which to work.

Comment: @Jonathen Leffler Yes, I can see the horizontally flip on the debugger. Thank you, again for your time and help. I think is something wrong with my display function.